# How do I search for all the columns/field names starting with "XYZ" in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I would like to do a big search on all field/columns names that contain "XYZ".

I tried below sql but it's giving me an error.

SELECT

table_name

,column_name

FROM **information_schema.columns**

WHERE column_name like '%account%'

order by table_name, column_name

ERROR states "Table or view not found: **information_schema.columns**; line 4, pos 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `information_schema.columns` is not supported in Databricks SQL. There are no in-built views available to get the complete details of tables along with columns. There is `SHOW TABLES` (database needs to be given) and `SHOW COLUMNS` (table name needs to be given).
- You might have to use Pyspark capabilities to get the required result. First use the following code to get the details of all tables and respective columns:

```
db_tables = spark.sql(f"SHOW TABLES in default")
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


final_df = None
for row in db_tables.collect():
    if(final_df is None):
        final_df = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE {row.database}.{row.tableName}")\
        .withColumn('database',lit(f'{row.database}'))\
        .withColumn('tablename',lit(f'{row.tableName}'))\
        .select('database','tablename','col_name')
    else:
        final_df = final_df.union(spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE {row.database}.{row.tableName}")\
        .withColumn('database',lit(f'{row.database}'))\
        .withColumn('tablename',lit(f'{row.tableName}'))\
        .select('database','tablename','col_name'))
#display(final_df)

final_df.createOrReplaceTempView('req')
```

[image]

- Create a view and then apply the following query:

```
%sql

SELECT tablename,col_name FROM req WHERE col_name like '%id%' order by tablename, col_name
```

[image]